# In Chrome if you remove iframe before download completes does it stop download?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome

I have an iframe whose source URL is a link to a file that the user requested to download. But I want to remove the iframe from the HTML once the download is complete. I've read that it is not possible to know when the download is going to get completed.

Suppose a user downloads a huge file and I remove the iframe from the page before it finished downloading, does it stop the download?

If it does, what would be the best alternative to this?

Comment: So what do you want? Do you want to continue downloading the file after you remove the `iframe` or stopping it?

Comment: Seems like it could be something that is testable....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The download will not stop unless chrome is closed